# Change color of navbar using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, nav

**HTML**

```
   <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="notDrop" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a class="notDrop" href="guides.html">GUIDES</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropbtn">BRANDS</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="gaming.html">NVIDIA</a>
                    <a href="#">INTEL</a>
                    <a href="#">CORSAIR</a>
                    <a href="#">SAMSUNG</a>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropbtn">BUILDS</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="gaming.html">GAMING</a>
                    <a href="#">OFFICE</a>
                    <a href="#">SERVER</a>
                    <a href="#">MEDIACENTER</a>
                    </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
    nav {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    window.onload = function mobile(){
    if( isMobile.any() ) {
        document.getElementById('nav').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
       alert('Mobile'); 
    }
}
```

> But I can't get it to change color, what am I doing wrong? I managed
>   to change the color of the body but I cant of the nav.

Comment: can you share the html for `nav` bar

Comment: Give the nav element an ID and change the getElement call to use that ID.  Nav is the element type - not its ID.

Comment: @Leyer What about `alert('Mobile');`? Is it working fine?

Comment: how many nav tag is use id used in the page?

Comment: @Archer oh okey, I will try. Thanks

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy It works without the "document.getElementById('nav').style.backgroundColor = "blue";" code but not with it.

Comment: @Leyer Then pls look at the ans

Comment: @brk only one if I understand you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong javascript function. `nav` is a tag, not an id.

It should be `getElementsByTagName("nav")[0]` instead of `getElementById("nav")`

javascript will always return an array regardless of number of matching element using `getElementsByTagName()` method. So use `[0]` to return the first one.

Comment: Is it the first nav element on the page?

Comment: Are you sure? He has not added any html

Comment: @Mendax Now he has posted his html code. Still I insist this ans will work

Comment: This answer needs clarification for people that end up here looking for help.  Please explain it, and specifically mention that if they ever add another nav element to the page it may stop this working.

Comment: Just another question, if I had css like this: nav a { css in here } how would I put it in the element?

Comment: @Leyer you can use two times the `getElementsByTagName`. (But you need to use for loop to loop through each `a` element) Personally I will suggest you to use jQuery library. There you can enjoy simpler methods.

Answer (score 0):

You used document.getElementById but you have only nav tag from HTML5. Add id = "nav" to your nav tag.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are using `getElementById`, but have not given your nav an id.

The best way to solve this would be to add an id to your nav, as follows:

```
<nav id="top-nav">
```

And your js becomes:

```
document.getElementById('top-nav').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

The answer given by *Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy*, while it will work is impractical because it looks for any `<nav>` tag, so if you add more `<nav>` tags, or move them around, you will have to recode your javascript.

By using an id, the javascript will always target the right `<nav>`.